# can't get the right output from a "group by"

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, group-by

Trying to get the list of product Id's with amount of feedbacks each of them has
Need to count only feedbacks that were given to the product as belonging to specific category (see the SQL script: categoryId == 50). Product can belong to multiple categories.

```
productId, cnt
14,        0
16,        0  
15,        1
09,        2
10,        2
```

EDIT:

I came up with the LINQ to SQL below, to recreate the logic I expressed trough SQL script below. But the result is not the same. Can't get what's different with LINQ's logic from SQL script's?

LINQ to Sql:

```
var result = 
(
from pcl in db.productCategoryLookup
join p in db.products on pcl.productId equals p.productId
join f in db.feedbacks on p.productId equals f.feedbackId into bb
from g in bb.DefaultIfEmpty()
where (pcl.categoryId == 50)
group p by p.productId into grp
select new
{
    productId = grp.Key,
    cnt = grp.Count()
} into res1
orderby res1.cnt
select new
{
    producetId = res1.productId,
    cnt = res1.cnt
}
)
.Take(5)
.ToList();
```

SQL Script:

```
 SELECT TOP 5
        p.productId,
        COUNT(f.feedbackId)
    FROM ProductCategoryLookup pcl
    INNER JOIN Product p
        ON p.productId = pcl.productId
    LEFT JOIN Feedbacks f
        ON f.productId = p.productId
    WHERE 
        pcl.categoryId = 50
    GROUP BY
        p.productId
    ORDER BY
        COUNT(f.feedbackId)
```

Tables:

```
**Products** table
productId   PK
productName  string

**ProductCategoryLookup** table. Connects products with Category.
One product can have multiple categories and the feedback goes 
for given product in given category.
productId   FK
categoryId  FK
. . .

**Feedbacks** table. Each product+category pair gets zero or more feedbacks.
feedbackId   PK
productId    FK
categoryId   FK
 . . .

**Category** table. 
categoryId   pk
name
```

To the answer from AD.Net I added join after 'from' for the productCategoryLookup, and where clause. Works now! Thanks.

Comment: There seems to be some 'magic' with the COUNT that I don't get for now

Comment: What's the actual problem?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: The actual problem is trying to get top 5 products with least feedbacks (not the worst, but just amount of feedbacks). Feedbacks are recorded in Feddback table.

Comment: Ok, but what's not working?

Comment: It's running but the Count is all 1 for my code. For the code @AD.Net suggested it seems to be working fine, but not giving number of product feedback's with categoryId == 50 (see the post) but listing all possible variants I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(from p in context.Products
select new {Product = p, Count = p.Feedbacks.Any() ? p.Feedbacks.Count() : 0})
.OrderBy(p=>p.Count)
.Take(5)
.Select(p=>p.Product)
.ToList()
```

Comment: OP also had a .ToList()

Comment: Thanks, this is much better then mine ... but the results are even farther from what's required. At Least this gives me a new direction to try!

Comment: By the way, did you left context.productCategoryLookup out on purpose?

Comment: No, if you want just the Products with least feedback it should do it. BTW, it should be orderby only, not orderbydescending which is the other way.

Comment: Thanks @AD.Net, Please read the edited question on the top of the post. I think I clarified the need for categories. Your answer is perfect, not considered that I need to consider feedbacks given to products + category not just product.

Comment: ok, then you can also get the categoryid, group by it and then do the orderby and take(5)

Comment: I added join after 'from' for the productCategoryLookup, and where clause. Works now. Great job!!

Answer (score 0):

Try following query. It may help you.

```
db.Products.Select(n => new { n.ProductID, count = n.Feedbacks.Count})
                .OrderBy(m=>m.count).Take(5).ToList();
```